# Setting up a dedicated Executor per ServerConnector in Jetty

Tags: java, configuration, jetty, devops, jetty-9

I'm trying to configure a dedicated executor in `jetty.xml` (jetty-9) for each of my `ServerConnector`s, as I'm able to do in Tomcat, but for some reason I get lost.

I'm using the following configuration:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New id="proxyConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
          <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
          <Arg name="acceptors" type="int">-1</Arg>
          <Arg name="selectors" type="int">-1</Arg>
          <Arg name="factories">
            <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
              <Item>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                  <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
                    <Arg name="compliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.http.compliance" default="RFC7230"/></Arg></Call></Arg>
                </New>
              </Item>
            </Array>
          </Arg>
            <Set name="host">127.0.0.1</Set>
            <Set name="port">50000</Set>
            <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
            <Set name="soLingerTime">-1</Set>
            <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta">0</Set>
            <Set name="acceptQueueSize">0</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Executors` are server-wide, and many components within Jetty expect that.

If you feel you need this, file an enhancement request at

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: Thanks @joakim-erdfelt for your answer, but are you completely sure it is impossible ? I do see a constructor that gets an `Executor` (http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html) and I'm just afraid I'm not familier enough with the IoC XML syntax...

Comment: It is possible - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1174#issuecomment-266965954 - just need to find the way to wire it using xml...